# Braintree - Advanced Fraud Tool

Tags: paypal, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I am trying to configure Braintree advanced fraud tool according to this documentation: https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/advanced-fraud-tools/configuration in sandbox mode. When I switch it on, it shows green as activated.

[image]

But when I refresh the page, it shows disabled again, there is no save button in the page. i.e. The options are saved as soon as we toggle the switch. How to enable this option?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. It was since I enabled this option:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VT0aG.png

After disable it, Advanced Fraud tool was successfully enabled.